# How to select next td tag of selected element by Laravel Dusk or WebDriverBy

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

I have a html like this:

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td> John Doe</td>
         <td> <a href="http://example.com/1/edit">Edit</a>  </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td> Robert Smith </td>
         <td> <a href="http://example.com/2/edit"> Edit </a> </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

I wanna to click on edit link of `John Doe`. What should I do? Is it possible with `WebDriverBy::xpath`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XPath:

```php
$selector = "//td[normalize-space()='John Doe']/following-sibling::td/a";
$browser->driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath($selector))->click();
```